Why is the "From"/Sender address in draft mails always empty? (And how to possibly get it?)
I am trying to download a draft (via IMAP) and send it (via SMTP) to people via MailKit.
Anyway, the problem is not sending or the process in general, but more a conceptual one: The Envelope.From in MessageSummary is always empty (empty string) and Envelope.Sender is null. Even though you usually see a sender being selected in your mail client.
This has been tested with:

Microsoft Exchange and Outlook
Docker Mailserver and Thunderbird

Why does this happen? This is IMHO quite an unexpected behavior as it differs from how users of mail clients "experience" such a draft mail.
So apart from hardcoding (or making it configurable) is there any way to get the (potential) senders mail of a draft?
Like maybe getting the mail address of the associated account or what is your supposed fallback?
And does it make sense to check the Envelope.From/Envelope.Sender for a draft anyway and only fallback or is it always empty?
Code
As per request this is how the mails are fetched from a folder (and then I select/find the correct one):
    public async Task<ICollection<IMimeMessage>> GetMessagesFromFolder(IMailFolder folder, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        await imapClient.Semaphore.WaitAsync(ct);
        try
        {
            await imapClientConnector.ConnectAndAuthenticateIfNeeded(imapClient, ct);
            await imapClient.NoOpAsync(ct);

            await folder.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadOnly, ct);
            var result = new List<IMimeMessage>();

            for (var i = 0; i < folder.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }

                var message = await folder.GetMessageAsync(i, ct);
                result.Add(message);
            }

            await folder.CloseAsync(false, ct);

            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            imapClient.Semaphore.Release();
        }
    } 


When you call the ImapFolder.Fetch/FetchAsync() method, how are you calling it?

@jstedfast I do useGetMessageAsync from IMailFolder to fetch all mails from a folder, and then find the one I need by it's Subject.

Then how are you getting the MessageSummary?

Can you post your code? That would help considerably.

Added and checked it again. It was refactored to not use MessageSummary again and it seems the actual IMImeMessage indeed contains the from address! That's good and thanks for your help!

An unsent message does not have an envelope, as this is a feature of the SMTP transaction in which it was sent.

Ah okay, more debugging and it turns out that it is Microsoft Exchange (Outlook) thing. There mail drafts just have an empty From even in MImeMessage. Well... okay. In docker mailserver (which uses Dovecot) From is set.
